# How to discern, whether my Python-module is invoked by Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible

I have a few Ansible-modules of my own under `playbooks/library/`. They are written to accept arguments either from command-line, or via `stdin`.

The scripts detect this, using the `os.isatty(1)` method:

```python
if os.isatty(1):
    # process sys.argv
else:
    from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
    main()
```

However, after upgrading to ansible 2.7, the above check began returning true even when the script is invoked by Ansible and the code started trying to process the (non-existent) positional arguments...

A quick check of environment variables does not show anything useful either -- the only hint is the filename: when Ansible transfer the module-script to the remote host, it is currently saved under name of AnsiballZ_*mymodule*.py

Can one rely on that, or is the naming convention likely to change too? What's the "right" way?

Comment: Does good ol' `if __name__ == '__main__':` not apply for this situation?

Comment: Neah, it is that in both cases -- the script is run as its own process either way. Just differently...

Answer (score 0):

> when Ansible transfer the module-script to the remote host, it is currently saved under name of `AnsiballZ_mymodule.py`

While relying on that last component of the pathname is likely not a safe choice, at least when I tried it I found that the *full* path was `/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1542695434.426839-2676176/AnsiballZ_mymodule.py` and so unless you are expecting anyone else to run your script from within `.ansible/tmp`, I think `if ".ansible/tmp" not in argv[0]:` is a perfectly fine metric for deciding if it is being run interactively or not.

Comment: The path -- `.ansible/tmp` -- is controlled by the `remote_tmp` setting in `ansible.cfg`. That is, it could be different for someone else. That said, yes, analyzing the `__file__` variable does give a clue, but it all seems hacking and unreliable. I was hoping there is some other indication...